# gridView Layout not showning and i got black screen

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, gridview, android-asynctask

i am trying to make `GridLayout` that each block will be movie poster. i using themoviedb.org to do that. i think that i did everything right but there still nothing showing in my application can someone please help me with my code.

i have 3 classes and 1 xml file

1) first class is MainActivity:

```
package com.example.admin.movies;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

2) Second class is MainFragment that is the fragment that i want to work with and inner AsyncTask class that show take "poster_path" from JSON query :
package com.example.admin.movies;

```
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 11/7/2016.
 */

public class MainFragment extends Fragment {


    private ArrayList<String> imagesEndPointsList;

    public MainFragment(){

    }
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        GetImagesAsyncTask sync = new GetImagesAsyncTask();
        sync.execute();

        setHasOptionsMenu(true);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,container,false);

        GridView gridView = (GridView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.grid_movies);
        gridView.setAdapter(new ImageAdapter(getContext(),imagesEndPointsList));

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),""+position,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
    }

    public class GetImagesAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,String[]> {

        private String [] imagesEndPoints;
        final private String LOG_TAG = GetImagesAsyncTask.class.getSimpleName();
        //My API Key to https://www.themoviedb.org/
        String myKey;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();

            myKey = "29a99f9dc266ab3a2108e9f9511a05ed";
        }

        @Override
        protected String[] doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // These two need to be declared outside the try/catch
            // so that they can be closed in the finally block.
            HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            // Will contain the raw JSON response as a string.
            String forecastJsonStr = null;
            String API_KEY = "api_key";

            try{
                final String BASE_URL =
                        "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/popular?";

                Uri buildUri = Uri.parse(BASE_URL).buildUpon()
                        .appendQueryParameter(API_KEY,myKey).build();

                URL url = new URL(buildUri.toString());

                urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Read the input stream into a String
                InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();
                StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
                if (inputStream == null) {
                    // Nothing to do.
                    return null;
                }

                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));

                String line;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    // Since it's JSON, adding a newline isn't necessary (it won't affect parsing)
                    // But it does make debugging a *lot* easier if you print out the completed
                    // buffer for debugging.
                    buffer.append(line + "\n");
                }

                if (buffer.length() == 0) {
                    // Stream was empty.  No point in parsing.
                    return null;
                }
                forecastJsonStr = buffer.toString();
                Log.v(LOG_TAG,forecastJsonStr);
                return getMovieDataFromJson(forecastJsonStr);
            }catch (IOException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error ", e);
                // If the code didn't successfully get the weather data, there's no point in attempting
                // to parse it.
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (urlConnection != null) {
                    urlConnection.disconnect();
                }
                if (reader != null) {
                    try {
                        reader.close();
                    } catch (final IOException e) {
                        Log.e(LOG_TAG, "Error closing stream", e);
                    }
                }
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String[] string) {
            super.onPostExecute(string);
            if(string != null) {
                imagesEndPointsList.clear();
                for (String dayForecastStr : string) {
                    imagesEndPointsList.add(dayForecastStr);
                }
            }

        }

        private String[] getMovieDataFromJson(String JsonString) throws JSONException{

            // Weather information.  Each day's forecast info is an element of the "list" array.
            final String OWM_RESULT = "results";

            final String OWM_PATH = "poster_path";

            try{
                JSONObject forecastJson = new JSONObject(JsonString);
                JSONArray imagesArray = forecastJson.getJSONArray(OWM_RESULT);

                imagesEndPoints = new String[imagesArray.length()];

                for (int i = 0 ; i<imagesArray.length(); i++){

                    JSONObject dayForecast = imagesArray.getJSONObject(i);

                    imagesEndPoints[i] = dayForecast.getString(OWM_PATH);
                    return imagesEndPoints;
                }
            }catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e(LOG_TAG, e.getMessage(), e);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

3) The Adapter that i built:

```
package com.example.admin.movies;

import android.content.Context;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.ArrayList;

/**
 * Created by Admin on 11/7/2016.
 */

public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    final private String BASE_URL =
            "http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w185/";
    Context mContext;

    private ArrayList<String> endPoints;

    public ImageAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> arrayList){
        mContext = context;
        endPoints = arrayList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return endPoints.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position)
    {
        return endPoints.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ImageView imageView;
        if(convertView == null){
            // if it's not recycled, initialize some attributes
            imageView = new ImageView(mContext);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(85, 85));
            imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
            imageView.setPadding(8, 8, 8, 8);
        }else{
            imageView = (ImageView)convertView;
        }

        Log.v("BASEURL",BASE_URL+endPoints.get(position));
        Picasso.with(mContext).load(BASE_URL+endPoints.get(position)).into(imageView);
        return imageView;
    }
}
```

4) And the xml layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.example.admin.movies.MainFragment">

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/grid_movies"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:columnWidth="90dp"
    android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:gravity="center" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Comment: from where you are loading `MainFragment `?

Comment: from the XML. no ? tools:context="com.example.admin.movies.MainFragment" ... @RaviRupareliya

Comment: you don't use your MainFragment anywhere. tools:context only sets a preview for AndroidStudio to render.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem relies on your getView() of the adapter, just create an xml with an imageView and use this resource as item for each row instead of creating your imageView programatically.

```
@Override
```

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

```
ViewHolderItem viewHolder;

if(convertView==null){

    // inflate the layout
    LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) mContext).getLayoutInflater();
    convertView = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

    // well set up the ViewHolder
    viewHolder = new ViewHolderItem();
    viewHolder.imageViewItem= (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    // store the holder with the view.
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);

    }else{
        viewHolder = (ViewHolderItem) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // object item based on the position
    String url = BASE_URL+endPoints.get(position);

    // assign values if the object is not null
    if(url!= null) {
          Piccaso. ---.into(imageViewItem);     
    }

return convertView;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

`tools:context="com.example.admin.movies.MainFragment"` does not tell Android to replace a `FrameLayout`. it just makes Android Studio to render a preview with fragment.

If you want to add fragment through XML, you need to do this:

```
<fragment class="com.example.admin.movies.MainFragment"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</fragment>
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that AsyncTask finish before you are setting Adapter?

You need:

1. Start AsyncTask in OnCreateView
2. Set adapter to your GridViewIn onPostExecute after you have list
3. Check if list is not empty